# Multiple inputs and after if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, web-scraping, input

I am trying to build a web scraper for jobs.
Now, I am trying to add a multiple-input that will be checked by an if statement.

This is the code:

```
html_text = requests.get('https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=python&txtLocation=').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text , 'lxml')
print ('Write Your Skill That you are less familiar with')
unfamiliar_skill = input (">")
print (f'Filtering out {unfamiliar_skill}')

def find_jobs():
    jobs = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx")
    for job in jobs:
        published_date = job.find('span', class_ = "sim-posted").span.text
        if "few" in published_date:
            company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = "joblist-comp-name").text.replace(' ','')
            require_experiance = job.find('ul', class_ = "top-jd-dtl clearfix").li.text.replace("card_travel", '')
            skills_requirment = job.find('span', class_="srp-skills").text.replace(' ','')
            location_of_the_job = job.find('ul', class_ = "top-jd-dtl clearfix").span.text
            for_more_info = job.find('header', class_ = "clearfix").h2.a["href"]
            #for_more_info = job.header.h2.a["href"]
            have_unfamiliar_skill = False
            for skill in unfamiliar_skill:
                if skill not in skills_requirment:
                    have_unfamiliar_skill = True
            break

            if not have_unfamiliar_skill:
                print("necessary information")

                print(f"Company Name: {company_name.strip()}") 
                print(f"Require Experiance: {require_experiance.strip()}")
                print(f"Skill Requirment: {skills_requirment.strip()}")
                print(f"Location Of The Job: {location_of_the_job.strip()}")
                print(f"For More Info: {for_more_info}")
                print('')
```

This is the Output:

```
Write Your Skill That you are less familiar with
>linux,sql
Filtering out linux,sql
```

Hope someone will help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some example for your input and `skills_requirment`

Comment: Here error is coming as you are doing `in` match for a `list` in a `string` .  Check type of `skills_requirment`. Convert it to list to get it working for you.

Comment: @Amin ,sure, examples like: Django,Linux,web scraping...

Comment: @aberry, I change the skill_requirment to a list:
``` skills_requirment = list(job.find('span', class_="srp-skills").text.replace(' ',''))```
but now the problem is that the output of it looks like a list:
Skill Requirment: ['\n', 'p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', ',', 'w', 'e', 'b', 't', 'e', 'c', 'h', 'n', 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'i', 'e', 's', ',', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'u', 'x', ',', 'm', 'o', 'b', 'i', 'l', 'e', ',', 'm', 'y', 's', 'q', 'l', ',', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'j', 's', ',', 'j', 'a', 'v', 'a', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', '\r', '\n', '\r', '\n']

How can I solve it now?

Comment: Can you share what you get output of skills_requirment  at line` skills_requirment = job.find('span', class_="srp-skills").text.replace(' ','')` . it seems it is already single string and hence `list` give you list of chars.

Comment: @aberry, I guess that you mean without the list.
```Write Your Skill That you are less familiar with
>django,linux
Filtering out ['django', 'linux']
--------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     15         for_more_info = job.find('header', class_ = "clearfix").h2.a["href"]
     16         #for_more_info = job.header.h2.a["href"]
---> 17         if unfamiliar_skill not in skills_requirment:
     18 
     19             print(f"Company Name: {company_name.strip()}")
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do check list in list. But in operator not working like that.

You can check every element and after that print necessary information.

```
have_unfamiliar_skill = False
for skill in unfamiliar_skill:
    if skill not in skills_requirment:
        have_unfamiliar_skill = True
        break

if not have_unfamiliar_skill:
    print("necessary information")
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer but I am not sure that I understand it.
I want that I will provide the input for the "unfamiliar_skill" (it could be one option or even two)

Comment: If unfamilliar_skill is a list which i'm seeing you're splittin with comma, you have to check each element one by one. For example skills_req = ['python','sql'], unfamiliar_skills=['sql','c++','pascal']. You cant check via unfamiliar_skill not in skills_requirment, because 2 side of in operator is list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand what you mean now.
Although, I have some problems implementing it on the code, there is a possibility that you can help me with it?

Comment: You can post the error here i think.

Comment: I try to convert both - unfamilliar_skill & skill_reqiurement to str and I didn't get any error, but the filter is not working properly .

Comment: You don't have to convert skill_requirement. Please add your code to question as a new edit and we can talk about it

Comment: sorry for the delay, I was very busy. I change it in the edit.

Comment: You are not calling your find_jobs() method anywhere. You should call your method.